# IIS / SQL Server connection error after adding windows auth

Tags: sql-server, iis, connection-string

I have a webapplication running using *Anonymous Authentication* and a connectionstring to a SQL server with a dedicated SQL-account. Connectionstring:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Everything works fine but after adding access control to the application:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
            <add accessType="Allow" roles="DOMAIN\ADGroup" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

And change to *Windows Authentication* in the IIS the pages using a connection to the SQL-server stops working. I havn't changed the connectionstring. Error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
> Specified)
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
> current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
> error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
> server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
> name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
> connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
> Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
> exception, Boolean breakConnection) +6318697
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj) +245    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo
> serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean
> ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean
> trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection
> owningObject, Boolean withFailover) +536
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
> serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64
> timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean withFailover) +283
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String
> host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
> SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
> Int64 timerStart) +6338834
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
> owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String
> newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6338792
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
> String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
> redirectedUserInstance) +354
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
> options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
> DbConnection owningConnection) +300
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
> owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) +45
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
> owningConnection) +6343166
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
> outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +6343479
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +258
> System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server,
> String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
> connectionString) +115
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server
> database.]
> System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server,
> String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
> connectionString) +4052597
> System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String
> server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String
> connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures
> features, Boolean install) +159
> System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String
> fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +825

Example usage of the connectionstring:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you add TCP/UDP port rule for SQL?

Comment: @EminNiftiyev Hi, I am not sure why I should change anything like that? Everything works again as soon as I back to Anonymous Authentication on the webapplication in IIS. All I want is to restrict access to the published webapplication. I havn't got access to the SQL-server.

Comment: That should not happen.  Can you provide a short, self-contained repro?

Comment: @Plarsen  if you try to connect to sql server by IP then IIS will throw an error. so you need to enable TCP protocols. The reason why visual studio works is that it is located in the same local area

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Okay, I am sorry but I am unable to do that.

Comment: @EminNiftiyev I am not following you. The connection to the SQL database works fine. It stops working when I change the authentication settings in IIS.

Comment: " I am unable to do that." --well what you describe is unlikely.  That's a network connection failure to SQL Server, and should not be affected by the web server's auth scheme. So if you can't repro it, there's probably something else going on.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Oh, it is definitely happening -- but what I meant was I am currently unable to reproduce it because I am not an administrator that has servers and access rights at my hands to setup a test-environment. I change between anonymous access and windows auth and the error comes and goes, so in a way I am reproducing it multiple times.

Comment: With `CreateMdfFile` in the stack trace it seems like it's trying to connect to a `(LocalDb)` instance. Does it work if you use `Data Source=tcp:YourServerNameOrIpAddress;` instead?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Good Catch.  And OP, in addition to switching to Windows Auth, are you _also_ setting impersonation in IIS?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I will test that. EDIT: Didn't help, the error message takes like a minute before showing up, seems like a timeout.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Nope, not impersonation .. I have to do that? I still want to use the SQL-account for the connection to the database.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using a local .MDF file on the web server, and not a remote SQL Server?  The .MDF file may be for ASP.NET Identity, and not your main database.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The database is on a separate SQL-server, but I also have a logging-function that add rows to local .txt-files :
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(
   Server.MapPath(".") + @"//Logs" + Request.ServerVariables["URL"].ToString() + "_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM") +".txt");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With CreateMdfFile in the stack trace it seems like it's trying to connect to a (LocalDb) instance.

I have a theory.  This actually makes sense if you're connecting to a local database file using SQL Express or LocalDb because file access depends on the identity the code is running under.  But making a TCP/IP connection to a remote SQL Server, even using the Browser service does not.

And in IIS Anonymous requests run as IUSR by default, and Windows Auth runs as the [App Pool Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities), eg `DefaultAppPool`.

So grant full control of the folder containing the database, and make sure that the database files have ACL inheritence enabled, or seperately grant full control on those to the App Pool Identity.

Comment: It's a database on a separate SQL-server, I have also tried changing the dns-alias to the ipaddress in the connection-string, without success.

Comment: Perhaps that's not the connection that's failing.  Something is trying to access a local .mdf file.  Do you have more of the failure's stack trace?  What is calling `System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile`?

Comment: Nothing I can find calls that... but perhaps this?
System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; 
    string logLine = System.String.Format(
     "{0:G}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{1}", System.DateTime.Now, Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToString(), GetIPAddress(), userName, msg, System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]).HostName);
    sw.WriteLine(logLine);

Comment: No.  The stack trace should start earlier.

Comment: I will try disable as much as I can, I think you are right - it's perhaps not the connection at all causing this.

Comment: Thank you, the issue where somewhere else not related to the SQL connection at all!

Comment: For anyone else finding this question searching for the same error msg, invalid use of this line of code caused the problem: System.Web.Security.MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser();